# Narrow union type based on a property

Tags: typescript

I am running into an issue when I try to narrow a type based on a property. It's best if I show with some code what it it basically boils down to:

```js
type User = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

type CreateUser = {
  name?: string;
}

const user: User | CreateUser = { name: "Foo Bar" };

if (user.id) {
  console.log(`Hello ${user.name}`)
}
```

So my thinking is that `user` is either a `User` or a `CreateUser`, and we can see the difference based on the existence of the `id` property. But sadly this doesn't work: `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'CreateUser'`. And `user.name` is still `string | undefined` instead of a simple `string`. Surely there is way to do this, but I am not able to find out how?

Even this doesn't work, which surprised me:

```js
if ("id" in user) {
  console.log(`Hello ${user.name}`)
}
```

I get `Property 'name' does not exist on type 'never'.`.

Comment: Are we allowed to change the types themselves or the type of `user`?

Comment: Rather not, but if it's the only way.. 

Answer (score 2):

When using a type annotation and initializing a value, the compiler is smart enough to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the value to the type that you use to initialize it. When initializing it with a type that has the `name` property and lacks the `id` property, the compiler narrows it to the `CreateUser` type:

```ts
const user: User | CreateUser = { name: 'Foo Bar' };

user;
//^? const user: CreateUser
```

To avoid this automatic narrowing behavior and preserve the union information in the same scope, you can use an [assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) instead of an annotation:

```ts
const user = { name: 'Foo Bar' } as User | CreateUser;

if ('id' in user) {
          //^? const user: User | CreateUser
  console.log(`Hello ${user.name}`);
                     //^? const user: User
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gKClAlgEwC4oA7AVwFsAjJAbm1IEMKJi5hFcSBzegX3qZQkKAGFEERsAjwkqDAxLMIAfjYcuvTAMyYAxgHsS7KGQTI06Ji2IByAGIGDUAEKNEtqHyiM4sc1AAPmISUjLmgrgAZlAAFLYEnlym5gCUCjiZWVAA9DkAeioMhsYGADYQAHRlBtyxAAYAEhBlNVAAJOhmSJVKLHz1qfTZI6OZeYXamEA)

---

Response to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73534568/narrow-union-type-based-on-a-property/73534631#comment129855145_73534631):

It works the same way when exporting a value. The important part is that *every time* you assign a value to the variable and want to preserve the full union type afterward in that scope, you must use an assertion to override the compiler's automatic narrowing behavior:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gKClAlgEwC4oA7AVwFsAjJAbm1IEMKJi5hFcSBzegX3qZQkKAGFEERsAjwkqDAxLMIAfjYcuvTAMyYIADzAB7RMCgAbCGbIJExWcgA+YiVJm3BNuWnRMWxAHIAMSMjKAAhRkQAqD4oRjhYWyhncUlpB0FcADMoAAoAghiuKC9EAEoFHGqaqAB6OoA9FQYAYyMSOCNLADpzI248gAMACQhzfqgAEnQynqUWPiHy+lq19eqG5u1MIA)

```ts
export let user: User | CreateUser;

user = { name: 'Foo Bar' } as User | CreateUser;

if ('id' in user) {
          //^? const user: User | CreateUser
  console.log(`Hello ${user.name}`);
                     //^? const user: User
}
```

and if this becomes tedious, just create an alias for the union:

```ts
export type AnyUser = User | CreateUser;

export let user: AnyUser;

user = { name: 'Foo Bar' } as AnyUser;
```

Comment: Kind of bizarre that `const user: User | CreateUser = { name: "Foo Bar" }` does not work, while `const user = { name: 'Foo Bar' } as User | CreateUser;` does work. The type looks the same for both.

Sadly this solution doesn't work for me though, as I have to annotate the type in my SvelteKit component: `export let user: User | CreateUser`.

Comment: @KevinRenskers See update

Comment: But the export is in my SvelteKit component, and the actual setting of that value is somewhere else, so sadly this doesn't work. The TS compiler can't see the types change from top to bottom in the same file. But I found a solution!

Comment: Thanks for the help though, I learned quite a bit from your example!

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```js
function isRealUser(user: User | CreateUser): user is User {
  return (user as User).id !== undefined;
}

if (isRealUser(user) {
  console.log(`Hello ${user.name}`)
}
```

Found on https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates.

Comment: Using a type guard works inside the `if` statement block, but — in the scope outside the block — `user` is still the type that it was after assignment (e.g. `CreateUser`).